# Loading - PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom

So I wrote the this code:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://page.com/');
$class = $html->find("div[id=aaaaaa]", 0)->innertext;
echo $class;
?>
```

Get the following error:
Loading…

Page load data with a delay (2 seconds) Can add delay load function ?

```
$class = $html->find("div[id=aaaaaa]", 0)->innertext
```

Have any ideas ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you sure that's an error, not the contents of the DIV that you're searching for?

Comment: BTW, `div[id=blah]` can be simplified to just `#blah`.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected class. I have a problem with loading.

Comment: In site is a script that loads the data from delaying

Comment: "loads the data from delaying". What does that mean?

Comment: @Barmar content loading via JS with delay after page opened.

Comment: If the page contains Javascript that builds the HTML, you'll need to use something like Mechanize to process it.

Comment: Have any ideas ? (example)

Answer (score 0):

"Loading..." is not an error. It is the content of the 'div[id=aaaaaa]' element node. In the browser this static content will replace replaced by JavaScript later.

Loading the page HTML source in PHP will not execute the JavaScript included in the page. You will need a headless browser like PhantomJS or SlimerJS for that.